# How can we access static variable without class name

Tags: java, static

How can we access static variable without class name? Static variable are always qualified with class name but in this case i am able to use it without class name.
how its possible??

```
    class Student
    {
    String  email;
    String name;
    long phone;
    static String school="jlc"; 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    Student st= null;
    System.out.println(school);//this should be Student.school but its working.
    }


    }
```

In below programme after creating student object, variables are already loaded into memory, but i cannot directly access it with out using object reference.but we can do for static.

```
class Student
{
String  email;
String name;
long phone;
static String school="jlc"; 

public static void main(String[] args)
{

Student st= new Student();
System.out.println(email);
}


}
```

Comment: You are **in** Student, so it's implict

Comment: here `main` method is `static`

Comment: below you cannot reference them because they do not exist statically. You have to specify which instance has them: `st.email` for example.

Comment: The same thing should worked for non static variable. After we create object, non static variable are loaded into memory, and we are in same class so can we directly access non static variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Static variable are always qualified with class name

First of all, it is not true you have to qualify with a class name, you can use a static import for instance:

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
```

Next you can refer to `Math.PI` simply by using `PI`. For example:

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI;

public class Foo {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(PI);
    }

}
```

More information can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

Next as long as you are **in the scope of the class**, all static members can directly be addressed without having to qualify. In other words this code fragment:

```
public class Foo {

    public static int static_member;

    //within this scope you can call static_member without Foo.

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works because you are inside the student class so it's implicit

```
public class Student {
    public static final String SCHOOL ="Harvard"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SCHOOL);
    }
}
```

Output: Harvard

```
public class Teacher {
    public static final String SCHOOL ="Harvard"; 
}

public class Student {
    public static final String SCHOOL ="MIT"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SCHOOL);
        System.out.println(Teacher.SCHOOL);
    }
}
```

Output: MIT

Output: Harvard

This also showcases why this work because now we can print both a teacher and a student which both have a school property.

The second part of your question:

You cannot call email directly because your Main method is static. So you will not only have to create the new student object but also use it.

```
 public class Teacher {
        public static final String SCHOOL ="Harvard"; 
        public String Email = "Test@Harvard.com";
    }

    public class Student {
        public static final String SCHOOL ="MIT"; 
        public String Email = "Test@MIT.com";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(SCHOOL);
            System.out.println(Teacher.SCHOOL);

            Student student = new Student ();
            System.out.println(student .Email);

            Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
            System.out.println(teacher.Email);
        }
    }
```

Output: MIT

Output: Harvard

Output: Test@MIT.com

Output: Test@Harvard.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide `ClassName.staticMemberName` only when your are referring it from outside the class.

In your case, your reffering static member within the class.

To answer your second question:

> Non-static members can't be used directly in a static method. It
>   should have object reference.

So, your statement should be like

```
System.out.println(st.email);
```

Comment: The same thing should worked for non static variable. After we create object, non static variable are loaded into memory, and we are in same class so can we directly access non static variable?

Comment: This is not about memory. You can create one more Student object in the same main(). Now if you directly say email which object email should java give?

Comment: thanks a lot Bhargav Kumar . Since instance variable can be used multiple time, so we need to specify which one.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a static method without referencing the class in the same class you are in, or through the use of a static import.

```
public class Student {
    public static void someStatic() {
    }

    public static void otherStatic() {
        someStatic(); //works
    }
}
```

Also:

```
import static Student.*;
public class OtherClass {
    public static void other() {
        someStatic(); //calls someStatic in Student
    }
}
```